# Convertir Unix Epoch en DateTime en Php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una pasarela API Rest la cual consulta datos a una base de datos MySQL. Dicha API Rest quiero que haga un barrido de datos de forma que lea lea las columnas nombradas en el código que voy a proporcionaros más abajo.

El tema de la cuestión es que tengo una columna de Unix Epoch llamada "fecha" la cual quiero transformar en un DateTime (y no sé cómo hacerlo!!) de forma que luego lo utilice para añadirlo a un array para trabajar con él.

Mis preguntas son las siguientes:

¿Cómo puedo convertir e dato Epoch a una variable de tipo string en formato de fecha lo más parecido a Y-m-d_H:i:s?
¿Está bien utilizar la misma variable para cambiar el formato de la fecha Epoch y luego volverlo a asignárselo a la misma variable para luego introducirla en un array?

```
<?php   
//CONECTARSE A BD Y COMPROBAR CONEXIÓN
  require_once "CONBD.php";
  $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
  if (!$conn) {          die("Fallo de conexión: " . mysqli_connect_error());    }

//1era CONSULTA 
  $sql = "SELECT sensorA, sensorB, sensorC, sensorD, sensorE, sensorK, sensorM, sensorN, sensorJ FROM pappGauges";
  $resultado = $conn->query($sql); 
  $json_array = array();  
  if ($resultado->num_rows > 0) {
     while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
        $sensoresA = $row["sensorA"];
        $sensoresB = $row["sensorB"];
        $sensoresC = $row["sensorC"];
        $sensoresD = $row["sensorD"];
        $sensoresE = $row["sensorE"];
        $sensoresK = $row["sensorK"];
        $sensoresM = $row["sensorM"];
        $sensoresN = $row["sensorN"];
        $sensoresJ = $row["sensorJ"];

        //FORMO UN ARRAY DE TODOS LOS SENSORES QUE HE COGIDO
        $sensores = array("sensorA" => $sensoresA, "sensorB" => $sensoresB, "sensorC" => $sensoresC, "sensorD" => $sensoresD, "sensorE" => $sensoresE, "sensorK"=> $sensoresK, "sensorM" => $sensoresM, "sensorN" => $sensoresN, "sensorJ" => $sensoresJ);

        //EMPUJO EL ARRAY
        array_push($json_array, $sensores);
        }
        //TRANSFORMO MI ARRAY A JSON
    }   echo json_encode($json_array);

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//2nda CONSULTA

$sql = "SELECT fecha, sensorA, sensorB, sensorC, sensorD, sensorE, sensorK, sensorM, sensorN, sensorJ FROM diario ORDER BY diario.id DESC";
$resultado = $conn->query($sql); 

//CONVIERTO VAR FECHA(EPOCH) EN UNA VAR TIME(Y-m-d_H:i:s)

$json_arrayd = array();
    if($resultado->num_rows > 0)    {
        while($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            //CONVIERTO VAR FECHA(EPOCH) EN UNA VAR TIME(Y-m-d_H:i:s)
            $fechas->DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d_H:i:s", $row["fecha"]);
            $fechas = $row["fecha"];
            $sensoresdA = $row["sensorA"];
            $sensoresdB = $row["sensorB"];
            $sensoresdC = $row["sensorC"];
            $sensoresdD = $row["sensorD"];
            $sensoresdE = $row["sensorE"];
            $sensoresdK = $row["sensorK"];
            $sensoresdM = $row["sensorM"];
            $sensoresdN = $row["sensorN"];
            $sensoresdJ = $row["sensorJ"];

       //FORMO UN ARRAY DE TODOS LOS SENSORES QUE HE COGIDO
       $diarios = array("fecha" => $fechas, "sensorA" => $sensoresdA, "sensorB" => $sensoresdB, "sensorC" => $sensoresdC, "sensorD" => $sensoresdD, "sensorE" => $sensoresdE, "sensorK"=> $sensoresdK, "sensorM" => $sensoresdM, "sensorN" => $sensoresdN, "sensorJ" => $sensoresdJ);

       //EMPUJO EL ARRAY
       array_push($json_arrayd, $diarios);
       }
       //TRANSFORMO MI ARRAY A JSON
   }   echo json_encode($json_arrayd);
 
//CERRAR CONEXIÓN CON BASE DE DATOS
  mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Esto responde a tu pregunta? [Convertir Epoch a Date PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13477788/convert-epoch-time-to-date-php)

Comment: Acabo de solucionar tal y como pone en el post que has mencionado, aún así muchísimas gracias! <3